# how can I control max parallelism with guaranteed FIFO?

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I am looking into using rabbitmq to manage my application's events. More specifically, I would like to:

1. make sure that I get FIFO processing of per-queue events: a new event is not processed until all previous events have been fully processed.
2. make sure that I can control the number of events that are executed in parallel.

A typical example is that I have 200 to 800 queues and I want to not allow more than 8 workers in parallel.

I have decided to use n+1 queues and n+m workers (n=200 to 800 and m=8):

- the first type of workers (n) is responsible for ensuring FIFO for
  all events within a queue
- the second type of workers (m) just execute the events in a parallel way

Here is pseudo code:

```
def queues_declare(channel):
    channel.queue_declare(queue='type1', durable=True)
    channel.queue_declare(queue='type1_callback', durable=True)
    channel.queue_declare(queue='type2', durable=True)

def type1(channel):
    def callback_type1(ch, method, properties, body):
        channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                              routing_key='type2',
                              body=body,
                              properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                                  reply_to = "type1_callback",
                                  correlation_id = method.delivery_tag,
                                  delivery_mode = 2,
                              ))
    def callback_type1_callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = properties.correlation_id)
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

    queues_declare(channel)
    channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    channel.basic_consume(callback_type1,
                          queue='type1')
    channel.basic_consume(callback_type1_callback,
                          queue='type1_callback')

def type2(channel):
    queues_declare(channel)

    def callback_type2(ch, method, properties, body):
        # XXX: do work !
        channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                              routing_key=properties.reply_to,
                              body='',
                              properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                                  correlation_id = properties.correlation_id,
                              ))
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

    channel.basic_consume(callback_type2,
                          queue='type2')
```

So, my question is: is this the right way to achieve what I want with rabbitmq ? Is there a better way to do this to control parallelism and ensure FIFO processing ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions mixed in here.

1. The only way to guarantee FIFO order is using a single queue for serializing access. And using a lot of workers that just re-publish messages to this single queue actually loosens that guarantee a bit - so it's better to setup a messaging fabric in a such way that messages will arrive straight to that queue.
   Anyway, biggest downside is that you performance is bound by performance of a single core of your CPU.
2. There is a way to limit concurrency using only RabbitMQ itself. You need to create a separate queue for this purpose and pre-fill it with the amount of messages equal to your required concurrency level. And then the first thing you worker should do is to try to get that message, but don't acknowledge it - so the message will be hanging in this non-acked state for a whole lifetime of a worker. When worker dies (or just closes AMQP connection), the message will become accessible to any other worker to pick it up. But again, there is a downside there - this works reliably only in a non-clustered environment. E.g. see https://aphyr.com/posts/315-jepsen-rabbitmq where almost exactly this use-case is being tested, among other things.